# Finding the partial derivatives of this function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $g \in C^1(\mathbb R)$ be a real valued function and $f$ defined by $$f(u,v,w) = \int_{u}^{v} g(w^2+\sqrt{s})\,\,ds$$ where $u,v,w \in \mathbb R$ and $u,v>0$.
Find all partial derivatives.

I'm not sure how to attempt this problem. I assume if it were a function of two variables, say something like $$f(x,w) = \int_{0}^{x} g(w^2+\sqrt{s})\,\,ds$$ then for example the partial derivative with respect to $x$ would just be $g(w^2 + \sqrt{x})$ (is that true?).

Anyhow, some hint or strategy would be very welcomed.

Comment: I believe with respect to x it would be $g(w^2 +\sqrt{x})$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, this is what I meant to write. I will edit it.

Comment: This function is not well defined. The domain is $\{ (u,v,w) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : u >0, v>0 \}$ because of that square root.

Comment: Thanks, fantastic observation. I shall edit this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $h(s) = g(w^2-\sqrt{s})$. When you compute the partial derivatives with rispect to $u,v$ the variable $w$ is fixed, hence you can think $h$ as a function $\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

So
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \int_u^v h(s) ds = - \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \int_v^u h(s) ds =- h(u)$$
since $v$ is considered a constant. In the same way you get
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial v} \int_u^v h(s) ds = h(v)$$
While for the third partial derivative you need to exchange the derivative with the integral sign, so you get
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w} \int_u^v g(w^2-\sqrt{s}) ds = 
\int_u^v \frac{\partial}{\partial w} g(w^2-\sqrt{s}) ds = 
\int_u^v g'(w^2-\sqrt{s}) 2w \ ds$$

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you sir.

Comment: You are welcome.